# meta tag and scaling text

Tags: html, viewport, meta

I have a non-responsive website on which I implemented a meta tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1400">
```

It seems to work just as I wanted it to when I tested on iPad (which was meant to be the hard part, I thought) - all the text and graphics scaled properly. I checked it on my Nexus later and it seems that some of the words just drop down to another line.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/haYGe.png

It's not about line-height property, because even on iPad they remain in proper line. The font-size just doesn't seem to scale with the rest in here.

Does anyone know what might be the reason? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Mobile browsers have an option like "**Auto-fit pages**" or "**Text wrapping**" so that the browsers can **format web pages to fit the screen width** when zoomed-in.

Try to disable this option and you will get your desired result.